# hacer que FORK devuelva dos resultados de diferentes comandos

Tags: c, linux

```
if (fork() == 0){
    execlp("date","date",NULL); 
    execlp("ls","ls",NULL); 
}
```

necesito que me entre la fecha y listar los archivos pero solo me muestra el primero que vendría siendo la fecha

Answer (score 1):

Cada vez que llamas a `fork()` estás creando un nuevo proceso. Si el resultado de `fork()` es distinto de 0 es que el proceso actual es el principal y, si no, es uno secundario.

Al crearse el segundo proceso se copia toda la memoria del proceso principal, de tal forma que los procesos no van a compartir memoria.

El caso es que después de `fork()` tendrás dos procesos que van a ejecutar el mismo código. También puedes identificar el proceso actual llamando a `getpid()`.

En cuanto a tu problema, el fallo se encuentra en el hecho de que las dos instrucciones están dentro del mismo `if`, luego únicamente las va a ejecutar uno de los dos procesos... el otro no va a hacer absolutamente nada porque no podrá entrar en el `if`. ¿Solución? Poner una instrucción en el `if` y otra en el `else`:

```
int pid = fork();
if( pid != 0 )
{
  // A ejecutar en el proceso principal
  execlp("date","date",NULL); 
}
else
{
  // A ejecutar en el proceso secundario
  execlp("ls","ls",NULL);
}
```

Ten en cuenta que si ambos procesos van a escribir en la consola sus resultados pueden entremezclarse (al ejecutarse en paralelo) generando mensajes extraños.

Un saludo.